# How friendly are learned friends supposed to be during court breaks?

Tags: lawyer, rules-of-court, professional-ethics, barristers

In a courtroom, just when everyone arrives before the hearing, how common or expected is it for the opposing lawyers to shake hands (covid aside) and have small talk pretending (or really being) friendly to each other?

In other words, would a lawyer who has never met the other one face to face before but has only communicated with them formally by email, be expected to just approach them before the hearing begins, shake hand and say the usual blablabla?

How does that extend to breaks in the middle, or when the hearing finishes?

Comment: Do you imagine they wouldn't be friendly? They almost certainly know each other and are colleagues in the legal profession. I know a coffee bar near a court where lawyers for both sides of cases take breaks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'd imagine it might be a wee bit of a challenge to be truly friendly if you _truly_ want to win the case. But if all you want is to suck as much money out of your client as possible then I agree it makes perfect sense to be real friends.

Comment: It's not really like that where I live, (UK) and I imagine elsewhere. The lawyers in my town all know each other, they may have gone to law school together, they are officers of the court, etc. A lawyer in court represents his or her client to the best of their ability, whichever side that is. A court case is not a fight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happens all the time, as the pool of local lawyers in certain specialties might be low.   In fact, not only can lawyers be friendly with each other, but they can also hang out after work while working on the same case.  In the often cited film "My Cousin Vinny", the titular Vinny, a defense attorney, is cordially invited to go hunting with the Prosecutor who is at present, prosecuting Vinny's cousin and client for First Degree Murder.   Not only does this happen (Vinny explaining this to his girlfriend is one of the funniest scenes in the film), but upon hearing about Vinny's horrible hotel living conditions (cheap hotels that are near increadibly loud noises in the wee hours of the morning) he offer to let Vinny stay at his hunting cabin to help matters (the film goes out of the way to avert the evil/amoral attorney trope as the prosecutor is only an antagonist and not a villain and what little we learn of his past history is quite sympathetic).

In fact, many lawyers have relationships with the judges that can be cordial (or not.  I recently heard of a humerous story of a lawyer who's biggest selling point is that he can ensure that you will never have your case go before an infamously terrible judge... because he and the judge have a bitter personal dislike of each other that forces the judge from recusing himself from any case where the lawyer is representing a party).   In fact, there's an old addage among lawyers that "Good Lawyers know the law, but GREAT lawyers know the Judge."  Basically knowing the judge's character and what arguements he'll be accepting of and what he will be not accepting of will help with getting a favorable outcome.

The evil or amoral lawyer trope actually stems from this because lawyers can and often on good terms with the guy who they are arguing against in a court room.   It's often like those Looney Tune cartoons where the sheep dog and the coyote beat each other up until the five pm whistle blows, they clock out, and then carpool home.

Comment: I just watched _My Cousin Vinny_. When the prosecutor invited Vinny to go hunting Vinny had just shown himself as a total clown in the courtroom. The prosecutor was not taking him seriously and was just having fun seeing him in informal context. I am not satisfied that was a genuine friends' hang out.

Comment: @Greendrake:  The point of the scene was to help humanize the prosecutor.  Pay close attention to that scene where he offers everything he has against Vinny's clients.  While he does have to do this, Vinny being a clearly new attorney and the Prosecutor's backstory (A defense attorney who decided to go to the prosector's office after getting a client who was guilty as sin off on some very serious charges) it could be thought he is sympathetic to Vinny's plight as a newly barred attorney who is defending a capital case.

Comment: We'll, he didn't offer everything. He had a surprise expert witness. Not a fair play, especially that the judge sustained it.

Comment: @Greendrake:  That was probably the least accurate part of the film... the judge overruling Vinny's objection would have likely come out on appeal, had it gone on, but as he said, he only got the results the moment he called Vinny.

Answer (score 5):

### About the same as it is for engineers, doctors, architects, hairdressers, plumbers etc. to be collegiate

It’s a job. You have shared interests (at least your profession). Why wouldn’t you be friendly?

It’s your client’s who have a dispute; not you.

Comment: Don't lawyers want to win and the opponent to lose?

Comment: @Greendrake haven’t you seen sportspeople shake hands (or hug) before and after a match? Competition doesn’t necessarily mean rivalry. Also, whether you win or lose depends at least as much on the cards you are dealt as how well you play them. Some hands are losers from the get go.

Comment: I don't know how sincere that is (as opposed to be mere protocol/etiquette).

Comment: @Greendrake my experience is that what happens on the court (both senses intended) stays on the court. Play to win, but play without malice. I’m probably never seeing my dispute resolution client ever again but I’ll see the other guy (and the arbitrator/mediator) next week.

Comment: A good lawyer does not want a guilty person to go free or an innocent person to be punished. Justice and the rule of law are more important than winning or losing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Actually a good lawyer represents their client to the best of their ability, within the rules laid down. That is true even if the defence lawyer knows that their client is guilty. A defence lawyer who sabotaged their client's defence because they were guilty is behaving unethically.

Comment: A defence lawyer cannot "know" that the client is guilty, surely? Isn't that for the court to decide?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey:  Attorney-Client Privelge exists specifically so the client can tell the attorney exactly what happened so the attorney can best represent his/her interests.  If you did in fact kill Colonel Mustard in the Conservitory with the Hammer, your attorney can mount a better defense knowning this than he can not knowing this.   They cannot lie in court, but they cannot be called to testify against you either.

Comment: @hszmv A lawyer cannot knowingly elicit false evidence. The details depend on the jurisdiction, but a client who confesses guilt to their lawyer prevents that lawyer from ethically pursuing some strategies that could lead to acquittal, while opening up the possibility of a favourable plea deal. Confessing guilt may be in the client’s interest, but it generally does not allow the lawyer to “mount a better defense.” https://ir.lawnet.fordham.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5269&context=flr

Comment: @sjy:  No, but there could be a situation where the prosecution is right for the wrong reasons OR the client might have been at the scene for some other unlawful purposes but didn't commit the crime he was accused of.   Knowing the full story can help the lawyer find the holes in the case that would exist.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it permitted, *best practices* are to be friendly and civil.

One of the important reason that lawyers are used in the legal system is so that difficult and technical discussions over a case, with respect to settlement or procedural matters, can take place between two people whose relationship with each other is not tainted by the events that gave rise to the litigation.

In a system in which more than 90% of criminal cases and more than 95% of civil cases are resolved prior to trial, often by settlement, an effective lawyer needs to be able to carry on a civil and productive conversation with opposing counsel in pretty much every case. And, an ability to do that, not just in the present case, but in general, for a lawyer's entire portfolio of cases, is greatly enhanced by having at least a minimal, civil, interpersonal social relationship with opposing counsel (especially in jurisdictions where the counsel are likely to encounter each other in more than once case, which is true in all but the very largest megacities and even then only in high volume practice specialties like Los Angeles County divorces).

Indeed, in Colorado, lawyers for each side are required to have a general and broad ranging discussion of the case with each other in the first few weeks of the case, pursuant to Colorado Rule of Civil Procedure 16, and are required to confer and discuss with each other every single proposed motion to be filed in the case before it is filed (and certify that the conferral has occurred or been attempted in a reasonable manner as the first time discussed on the first page of every motion) in an effort to find points of agreement that can simplify the litigation, pursuant to Colorado Rule of Civil Procedure 121, § 1-15.